# Checking the existance of a Telegram username with Telegram bot in Java

Tags: java, bots, telegram

How can I check if a Telegram user-name exist in Telegram or not with Java?

for example @sadema exsists and @sadeama doesn't exists.

this is my ***onUpdateReceived*** method , what should I insert in my ***if*** statement ?

```
@Override
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {

    SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
    sendMessage.setChatId(update.getMessage().getChatId());


    if ("@sadema" exists on telegram )
    sendMessage.setText("https://t.me/sadema");

    try {
        sendMessage(sendMessage);
    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @MárioFernandes thank you , I have edited my question , please read it again.

Comment: are you checking if exists while receiving updates? the username is the username of the user of the update? can you provide these info?

Comment: @91DarioDev I know that the user is sending message to the bot exists, I want to know if someone that doesn't send message to the bot exists or not

Answer (score 1):

There is no such an API for telegram Bots (to check whether a username is free or taken if this is what you want).

you need to use telegram API itself for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you , but please visit this bot : @idyab2bot, how can the creator of the bot build that bot ?

Comment: @sadimahman In these bots only the user interface is created via bot api, but at the back end the data is processed via telegram API and then passed to you via the bot.